# State management in amazon web services

Tags: amazon-web-services, state

How is state managed between sessions?  I know that in Azure, client-specific states are stored in SQL Azure.  I'm wondering if this is done similarly in AWS?

Do the various instances of your application all access a DB somewhere where the state is stored?  Is state management much different depending on which technologies you are using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At a 'homework' level, Amazon Web Services is loosely comprised of two different sets of things:

- infrastructure services (EC2, EBS), which you manage yourself
- higher level services (S3, DynamoDB, ELB), which Amazon manage for you

When you upload a file to S3, it is stored across a number of machines in a number of different data centers, and Amazon is responsible for finding and returning the file when you request it (as well as making sure it doesn't get erased by a machine failure.)

With something built on top of one of the infrastructure services, such as an application running on EC2, you are on your own as to how you store and synchronize state:

- One server, state in memory (bad)
- Load balancing with no state handling (very bad!)
- Load balancing with sticky sessions (sensible, but not enough by itself; if that server falls out of the pool, the other servers have no idea of who you are)
- Load balancing with servers with a common state server

How do you store state?  Traditionally a database (possibly Amazon [RDS](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/)) with a memory cache (such as [Elasticache](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/) - Amazon's managed memcached-compatible cache).  [Amazon's new DynamoDB service is a good fit for this use](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/04/scalable-session-handling-in-php-using-amazon-dynamodb.html), as a fast, redundant, key-value store.

Comment: In here there is a good article about it. [Link](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/elasticache-as-an-asp-net-session-store/)